# Distance element on a sphere

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, astronomy

I fail to understand the following part in a cosmology textbook (metrics chapter). If we set a polar coordinates system on the surface of a sphere of radius $R$ where $r$ is the distance from the north pole and $\theta$ the azimuthal angle measured relative to the prime meridian, then:
$$ds^2 = dr^2+R^2 \sin^2(r/R)d\theta^2$$

I fail to see how that $sin^2(r/R)$ came about, and will be glad for any clarification.
*I'm aware that is not directly connected to cosmology, but I thought it will be more familiar for people here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When close to the pole, some change of the azimuthal angle $d\theta$ implies a smaller change of position $ds$ than close to the equator, because the circle on which one moves is smaller. Since $r/R$ is the angle (in radians) between the pole and the circumference line of this circle, $R \sin(r/R)$ is it's radius, and consequentially $R\sin(r/R) d\theta$ is the change of position $ds$, if $r$ is constant. Then your formula for $ds^2$ can be obtained by using the Pythagorean theorem.

**Edit:**

To make a little clearer what I mean by the angle $r/R$, I drew the following image:[image: Figure for distance element explanation]

When $\phi$ is measured in radians, it is just the arc length on the unit circle corresponding to the angle. This arc length is obtained by dividing $r$ through $R$, so $\phi = r/R$. Then $R\sin(r/R)$ is the length of the horizontal cathetus in the image.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what is the $r/R$ angle you are talking about. Are you aware of some picture that shows it graphically which is available online maybe? Thanks!

Comment: In the sketch, θ is not the azimuthal angle. A different symbol would cause less confusion.

Comment: @R.W.Bird I got a little confused myself, because I usually call the polar angle $\theta$. I changed the symbol in both the figure and the text now.